# My log in isn't working

Tags: php, authentication

I'm getting error:

```
Undefined variable: user_data in loggedin.php
```

My register page is fine it register successfully users.When i log in it displays me all the information but not the user_data.If somebody can write me where is my fault.My 
init.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
$_SESSION['user_id'] = (int)1;
if(logged_in() === false) {
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile', 'textarea', 'writingname', 'writing');
echo $user_data['password'];
if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index2.php');
    exit();
}
}
$errors = array() ; 
?>
```

users.php :

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);
$fields = '`' . implode ('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

return $data;
    }
    }
function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

And my

```
loggedin.php :
<div class="widget">
<h2 onClick="document.location.href='index2.php'">Hello<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?> ! </h2>
<div class="inner">
```

Comment: can you show your error here?

Comment: it looks like your user_data function excepts only one parameter and you are sending more than one.

Comment: how to fix it @K.Uzair

Comment: and when i write in my init.php if(logged_in() === true) it shows me user_data, everything but only for the user that i log in before now it doesn't let me log in when its false with any.

Comment: Just use this `user_data($session_user_id);`

Comment: U also need to store username in session

Answer (score 0):

did you pass your $user_data from init.php to loggedin.php???
$user_data is not a session, so you can't just make $user_data in init.php and echo it in loggedin.php...
CMIIW

var_dump might help you tho'

Answer (score 0):

change you init.php code to this one below.

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
$_SESSION['user_id'] = (int)1;
if(logged_in() === false) {
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id);// just send user id here stored in session.
echo $user_data['password'];
if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index2.php');
    exit();
}
}
$errors = array() ; 
?>
```

Comment: Plz explain what u changed . this will help to OP and future visitors also

Comment: Тhanks guys everything is fine now

Comment: so where was the error in your code. Please explain so community could get help :)